# Continuous data transfer over bluetooth

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth

I would like to generate random numbers between 0 and 100 and transfer them continuously over bluetooth from a Raspberry Pi (running Linux) to an embedded (x86) PC (also running Linux). My C code is based on the following: -

Client Side: -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_rc addr = { 0 };
    int s, status;
    char dest[18] = "01:23:45:67:89:AB";

    // allocate a socket
    s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

    // set the connection parameters (who to connect to)
    addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
    str2ba( dest, &addr.rc_bdaddr );

    // connect to server
    status = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    // send a message
    if( status == 0 ) {
        status = write(s, "hello!", 6);
    }

    if( status < 0 ) perror("uh oh");

    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Server side: -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_rc loc_addr = { 0 }, rem_addr = { 0 };
    char buf[1024] = { 0 };
    int s, client, bytes_read;
    socklen_t opt = sizeof(rem_addr);

    // allocate socket
    s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

    // bind socket to port 1 of the first available 
    // local bluetooth adapter
    loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    loc_addr.rc_bdaddr = *BDADDR_ANY;
    loc_addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
    bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr));

    // put socket into listening mode
    listen(s, 1);

    // accept one connection
    client = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &opt);

    ba2str( &rem_addr.rc_bdaddr, buf );
    fprintf(stderr, "accepted connection from %s\n", buf);
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

    // read data from the client
    bytes_read = read(client, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if( bytes_read > 0 ) {
        printf("received [%s]\n", buf);
    }

    // close connection
    close(client);
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

While this works well for a single string, I am unable to transfer integers. Also, for a continuous data stream, do I just have the server and client running in a for loop (for example) or is there a better way  to do it?

Comment: - About being "unable to transfer integers": can you show the code that doesn't work instead of the one with the string, that does work?

Comment: did you take care of the different endianess of the systems when you try to send an int? Do you receive garbage or nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you want to send an Integer type data over BT RFCOMM socket but your base example requires `string` to be send.
Your solution is simply convert your number to string (`char` array in `C` language).

Your code comes from **Albert S. Huang** invaluable works on BT programming
[Great BT programming tutorial](https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html)

Apply these changes to your code.

## client

```
  // send
char integer[4];                  // buffer
*((int*)integer) = 73232;         // 73232 is data which I want to send.
//send( cs, integer, 4, 0 );        // send it

    // send a message to server
    if( status == 0 ) {
        status = write(s, integer, 4);
        if (status == 4){
            printf("Send data to server done\n");
        }
    }
    else 
        if( status < 0 ){ 
            perror("send message to server Failed\n");
    }
```

Its send 73232 to server.

## server

```
char integer [4];

bytes_read = read(client, integer, 4);

/*if( bytes_read > 0 ) {
    printf("received [%s]\n\n", buf);
}*/

printf("int: %x\n", integer[0]);//10
printf("int: %x\n", integer[1]);//1e
printf("int: %x\n", integer[2]);//1
printf("int: %x\n", integer[3]);//0
```

And server successfully receive every chunks of your number.
But as you see (I write them as comment ) they are store in LE form.

## 73232 = > 01 1e 10

(we can add a leading 0 digit to every numbers)

**Hint**: you can use an on line decimal to hex converter. [dec_to_HEX](https://codebeautify.org/decimal-hex-converter)

you catches them in revers form because of [endian](https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/).

And in this point you have them and can do some other operations.

As you said in example, your number must generated by a random function and its return value (your random) is send over BT socket.

my solution based on [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147633/send-and-receive-an-integer-value-over-tcp-in-c)