# Does send() allow you to pass an int array C

Tags: c, network-programming, send

I'm trying to send an encrypted message in a simple server-client chat program.

This is the `send()` call:

```
int send(int sockfd, const void *msg, int len, int flags);
```

Can I pass an `int` array as `*msg`?

Comment: already answered in [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147633/send-and-receive-an-integer-value-over-tcp-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the `send()` system call. But be aware, that the `len` is the **length of the message in bytes**. So i think for an array of 5 `int`. You need to specify the `len` as `5*(sizeof(int))`.

Additionally, on the receiving side, you need to interpret it accordingly.

As Naveen pointed out, a more detailed answer to your question is already present [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147633/send-and-receive-an-integer-value-over-tcp-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are allowed to pass an array of `int`s to `send()`. The reason you're allowed to do that is arrays are automatically converted to pointers when they are passed to functions. See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573310/difference-between-passing-array-and-array-pointer-into-function-in-c).

In addition, any pointer in C is can be automatically cast to `void *` if necessary. Void pointers were designed to provide implicit conversion.